# K6 scenarios to generate specific request per second rate

Tags: performance, grafana, k6

I wrote the following options with [K6 scenarios](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/#executors) for my performance testing in hoping to achieve traffics with different request per second while keeping the virtual users - VUs constant at 100.

```js
    export let options = {
    scenarios: {
        foo: {
            executor: 'ramping-arrival-rate',
            preAllocatedVUs: 100, //start & end at 100 VUs

            startRate: baseRPS, timeUnit: '1s',
            stages: [
                { target: baseRPS * 10, duration: '0s' },   // jump to 10 iterations/s immediately
                { target: baseRPS * 10, duration: '30s' },  // stay at 10 iterations/s for the next 30 seconds
                { target: baseRPS * 20, duration: '0s' },   // jump to 20 iterations/s immediately
                { target: baseRPS * 20, duration: '30s' },  // stay at 20 iterations/s for the next 30 seconds
                { target: baseRPS * 30, duration: '0s' },   // jump to 30 iterations/s immediately
                { target: baseRPS * 30, duration: '30s' },  // stay at 30 iterations/s for the next 30 seconds
            ],
        },
    },
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: true,
    };
```

The execution shows K6 went through each stage accordingly.  My goal is to identify if VUs contribute to the performance degradation or the request per second.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am surprised when I see the K6 result. Because it shows on average, it only generates around 7 request per second.

[image]

Did I do something wrong here in the option configuration or the 100VUs is not enough to generate more request per seconds?

Furthermore, my Grafana dashboard which I streamed my K6 test results to shows the Request per second rate never really change that drastically throughout my test durations.

[image]